# SharePoint 2007 integration Reporting Services 2005 having error!

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services

Previously the reporting services in SharePoint 2007 are working fine. Suddenly it appear an error as below:-

> The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
>
> at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall) at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.Execution.ReportExecutionService.LoadReport(String
>   Report, String HistoryID) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.LoadReport(String
>   Report, String HistoryID) at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.GetExecutionInfo() at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1
>   parameters) at UserControls_PortfolioSpend.btnProcess_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)

When I tried to edit the data source definition, it give me below error:-

> An unexpected error occurred while connecting to the report server.
>   Verify that the report server is available and configured for
>   SharePoint integrated mode.  Troubleshoot issues with Windows
>   SharePoint Services.

Besides that, SharePoint 2007 farm and Reporting Server are installed separately. Anyone are facing the same issue before? I have tried quite a number of solution from the MSDN, but still not able to resolve the issue.

Appreciate that anyone can suggest me what can I do for resolve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolved the issue by verify the services account that using in the reporting server which integrate with SharePoint Server. The services account delegate to the particular server that not part of reporting server. When remove the delegation for this services account in the AD. It solved my problem.

This required to using Kerberos Tracking method to trace which services account having problem.

Regards,
Yeoh Eik Den